# I changed codes in the running django project on the aws but changes are not reflecting

Tags: django, python-2.7, amazon-ec2

I have a running Django project on an AWS server with the website hosted on the same server. I changed some code and uploaded it to the server using SFTP server but changes are not reflecting on the website and uploaded file is not working.

Comment: How did you start your python process? Using UWSGI or anything else?

Comment: its running on localhost of ec2 instance

Comment: To be clear: you killed your process and restarted it ?
If yes, you might want to clean your *.pyc with `find . -name "*.pyc" -exec rm -f {} \;`

Comment: i cleared the .pyc files from whole project then changed the files and then started python process. Still its not working.

Answer (score 0):

Restart your server (`Apache`, `NGINX`, or any other server that you are using).

Comment: It's python, your'll need to restart the python process. No need to restart NGINX. It all depends on how server has been started